# How could I pass a list of files to a function and get the same list back with changes made to the files?

Tags: python, list, function

How can I send a list of files to a function, apply regex to the lines in each file in the list and return the new list?  I can write the changes to a new file but don't know how to replace the files in the list and send it back.  Here is my code:

```
def apply_regex(myList = [], *args):
   for index, item in enumerate(myList):
      file = open(myList[index], 'r')
      out_file = open(myList[index] + ".regex", "w")
      for line in file:
         line = re.sub('some_regex',r'some_thing_to_sub', line)
         out_file.write(line)
```

Function call:

```
listFile=['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
apply_regex(listFile)

#take some action on listFile based on the new values#
```

But I can't pass the new values from the function!  I know I have to write to the files within the def apply_regex but need help doing it and then passing it back.

Comment: You can get the same list back by adding a `return myList` at the end of the `apply_regex()` function. BTW, you probably shouldn't be giving `myList` a default value, especially a mutable one like a list.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally want to replace the items in the original list:

```
def apply_regex(myList = [], *args):

   for index, item in enumerate(myList):
      file = open(myList[index], 'r')
      out_file = open(myList[index] + ".regex", "w")
      myList [index] += ".regex"
      for line in file:
         line = re.sub('some_regex',r'some_thing_to_sub', line)
         out_file.write(line)
      out_file.close ()   # Flush buffer
```

Comment: Than you Jacques.  This is exactly what I wanted.